# After trying to update records I get "Value cannot be null"

Tags: asp.net-core

After I want to update a user records and when I press Update button  I get

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

Here is my function for updated user record:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, AppointmentDetailsViewModel objAppointmentVM)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                objAppointmentVM.Appointment.AppointmentDate = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.AppointmentDate
                    .AddHours(objAppointmentVM.Appointment.AppointmentTime.Hour)
                    .AddMinutes(objAppointmentVM.Appointment.AppointmentTime.Minute);

                var appointmentFromDb = _db.Appointments.Where(a => a.Id == objAppointmentVM.Appointment.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                appointmentFromDb.CustomerName = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.CustomerName;
                appointmentFromDb.CustomerEmail = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.CustomerEmail;
                appointmentFromDb.CustomerPhoneNumber = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.CustomerPhoneNumber;
                appointmentFromDb.AppointmentDate = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.AppointmentDate;
                appointmentFromDb.isConfirmed = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.isConfirmed;

                if(User.IsInRole(SD.SuperAdminEndUser))
                {
                    appointmentFromDb.SalesPersonId = objAppointmentVM.Appointment.SalesPersonId;
                }

                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(objAppointmentVM);
        }
```

This function is for Drop-Down menu which display the Users from DB

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItemString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string selectedValue)
        {
            if(selectedValue == null)
            {
                selectedValue = "";
            }
            return from item in items
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = item.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                       Value = item.GetPropertyValue("Id"),
                       Selected = item.GetPropertyValue("Id").Equals(selectedValue.ToString())
                   };
        }
```

Any Idea where I made mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your table's column is set to `not null`.

Go to SQL Server and open your table. In the design table window, check the `allow nulls` checkbox.

Comment: If this was a SQL issue it would have raised a SQL exception, not an LINQ argument exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your item select one of the items is null,  and LINQ is failing throwing an argument exception because you're trying to run a selector function on something that is null.